# Ubuntu Minimal + WICD Help

Tags: wireless, wicd, ubuntu-minimal

So I installed Ubuntu Minimal, Xfce4, and just a few applications. I used an Ethernet cable to do the install and worked off the Ethernet. However, now I need to connect to a WiFi network. I tried just installing WICD, and towards the end I get the [Starting wicd daemon: fail]. Something like that, I can't remember. When I install network-manager, all the options are completely greyed out.

I know that I can use command line to connect to networks, but I prefer to use a GUI for something like that. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: NetworkManager and WICD are kinda exclusive, so make sure you have only one or the other. More details on WICD's errors would help too.

Comment: Well the install output always gives me this: Setting up wicd-daemon (1.7.2.4-4) ...
 * Restarting Network connection manager wicd                            [fail] 


After that, manually trying it gives me the same fail error. I tried a restart, thinking Ubuntu Minimal would stop whatever network protocol it's using and use wicd, but it doesn't. In fact, wicd requests me to put in my root password, then says it cannot connect to the D.bus service. Something to that effect. After that, I can't use wicd at all.

Comment: I can't edit the one above this, but the error I get after manually try to start wicd (from the gui), I have to put in my password so that wicd can access my computer's network card, and then it says "Could not connect to wicd's d-Bus interface. Check the wicd log for error messages." I check the log, there's no file there.

Comment: I wonder if you're being affected by this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wicd/+bug/1132529. There seems to be a workaround [in this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wicd/+bug/1132529/comments/22).

Comment: I'll make that the answer to close this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are being affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wicd/+bug/1132529. You should be able to work around it with the following:

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
rm /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
```